# How to login to a different subdomain and different auth guard within the same project?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I have a project in Laravel and it has a store admin dashboard and a partners dashboard. Partners can get access to stores and they're listed in the partners dashboard where they have a "login" button to directly login into shop ie. admin dashboard.

Every time a partner gets access to a store they are added as a collaborator in the shop.

There is a different subdomain for partners:

```
Admin: abc.test
Partners: partners.abc.test
```

Now, there are 2 different guards for both models, for admin there's default `web` guard and for partners there's a `partners` guard.

How can I implement this login button, so that on clicking the partner is automatically logged into the admin account.

Comment: read this all is here https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-group-subdomain-routing

Comment: i have already set this up, but I need to login there

Comment: then apply middle ware base on subdomain

Comment: let me make it more clear, on clicking in login button inside partner dashboard where there is a list of stores partner has access to I want to login into the shop using the store credentials, both are on different subdomains and different guards @KamleshPaul

Answer (score 0):

try something like this here:

```
Auth::guard('web')->attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password]))
```